# Font Awesome Icons do not display correctly across browsers

Tags: html, css

I used some icons placed in my footer from font awesome that link to other pages. The icons load fine on my local server and they load fine on my codepen. However, the icons do not appear on internet explorer and my entire footer disappears from google chrome. What would cause this?

Here is the link to the codepen: http://codepen.io/sibraza/pen/QNPMdm
Here is the actual website: http://sibraza.com/

The HTML Code:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="filepath/font-awesome-4.6.3%202/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

 <div class="row">
        <div class="icons">
          <ul class="social">
            <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/syed-raza-374a1a89" class="button social"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://github.com/sibraza15" class="button social"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-github"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://codepen.io/sibraza/" class="button social"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-codepen"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: As a quick thought, do you use any ad blocking in your browsers?

Comment: They appear just fine on my local machine. I would suspect that there is an issue with how you are referencing the Font Awesome library. You might consider using the Developer Tools (F12) to check for any Network / Console errors that might provide some more information.

Comment: I do use ad blocking. And I think Rion might be right. I found this error in the console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: If it's a 404, then it's likely Rion's correct. Some ad-blockers do, however, block icons of social media sites, which would cause that behavior. Once you resolve the file path issues, if you're still not seeing them, try temporarily disabling your ad blocking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that your local version of font-awesome has some issues? Try using the [CDN](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/fontawesome/) link instead.

Here's a helpful link to troubleshooting page on the Github repository of font awesome: [Font awesome troubleshooting](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Troubleshooting)

**EDIT:**

**Error in the question owner's case:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="filepath/font-awesome-4.6.3%202/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

The reference to the question owner's copy of 'font-awesome.min.css' is malformed and has file path issues.

**Solution:**

*Option 1:* Make sure your reference file path is formed correctly and points to a valid copy of 'font-awesome.min.css'.

*Option 2:* Use a version provided by the [CDN](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/fontawesome/) like so

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that on the console :

`http://sibraza.com/Users/syedraza/Desktop/SibRaza.com/font-awesome-4.6.3%202/css/font-awesome.min.css  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

That's means you have some file path issues. As suggested by @Wyngaert try using the [CDN](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/fontawesome/) instead of hosting your own version.